# where do I put composer.json

Tags: php, composer-php

I have installed composer.

My project dir tree looks something like this

```
/home/myproject/public_html/myproject.com
```

I initially installed it in:

```
/home/myproject/public_html/myproject.com/bin/composer/
```

But later moved it to:

```
/home/myproject/usr/local/bin/composer
```

Questions:

1. Where to I create composer.json ?
2. In the official docs they mention that in order to install new packages I need to write a require key in the json format in that file, does this mean that I dont have to upload the package through ftp?
3. The docs further say that I can simply install dependencies like ths:

   php composer.phar install

I dont understand the workflow of this process (im fairly new).. what exactly do I need to do to get some packages going (like [Respect](https://packagist.org/packages/Respect/Validation))

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Composer has 2 basic elements for you to consider:

1. The composer.php file itself - this can be located anywhere on your system - usually it is convenient to have it in you search path so you can invoke it by name (no path) from the command line.
2. Composer.json - this file is the configuration for your project. This is usually best located at the top level of your project. Ideally this is a directory outside the scope of your web server - so that it will never be exposed or served.

Symfony2 has some great documentation and examples of composer in use.

Also be aware that some packages you reference via composer will themselves have composer files - to ensure they match your required dependancies - and they may also have their own dependancies that need to be considered.

I would install composer.json in the following

```
/home/myproject/composer.json
```

It would be out of scope of the web server and could be used to manage many assets e.g.

```
  public_html/
  libs/
  config/
  docs/
  vendor/
```

Comment: ok understood. Now what about actually installing the dependencies, I have a "vendor" folder in home/myproject/public_html/myproject.com/vendor/ , is this where I upload the package ? or will adding a require key in composer.json suffice ?

Comment: Again vendor is often located at the top level - as it may contain code and configs you do not want to be served via the web server.  While composer is very flexible Symfony2 for example keeps vendors out of public scope - but does provide asset management features to allow files / assets to be published into the web directory if they are needed.

Comment: "great documentation" on [composer.json files](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/best_practices.html#composer-metadata) for the record.

Answer (score 3):

> Where to I create composer.json ?

You should create `composer.json` to your project root like `/home/myproject/public_html/myproject.com/composer.json`. If all files of your application live inside your `myproject.com` folder.

> In the official docs they mention that in order to install new
>   packages I need to write a require key in the json format in that
>   file, does this mean that I dont have to upload the package through
>   ftp?

Yes as long as you're not in shared hosting because most of them don't allow CLI (SSH).

> The docs further say that I can simply install dependencies like this

```
php composer.phar install
```

Yes you can simple type the above command and composer.json will install the latest version of your package.

**Composer.json** (Respect Package)

```
{
    "require": {
        "respect/validation": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Now run `composer install` will install the require package.

For further packages

```
{
    "require": {
        "respect/validation": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/orm": "2.*"
    }
}
```

Now run update `composer update` it will download the `doctrine/orm` as well.

Comment: I already installed composer.json in /home/myproject/ , and you are right all files of my app live in /myproject/public_html/myproject.com/ , will it still work? i.e. can i still use dependencies in /myproject.com/ ?

Comment: Yes you can, as long as you require vendors `autoload.php` to your `/public_html/myproject.com/` application file.